# File progress for long duration

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, data-analysis

I am trying to fetch location based on lat and long. I have a data of 600K in my csv and I am trying to run my for loop on it . My notebook is taking very long time to process the data. ( 40min to complete 2percent)
I have decent laptop  Core i7-8550U quad-core 1.8GHz and 16GB DDR4 RAM . 
I am not sure how to optain the result for my data quickly .Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sample code of what you are doing ? Are you reading your file every time you fetch a latitude and longitude  If this is the case this is why it takes so long. First load the file in your memory as a pandas object for example and then you should be able to look for your data much faster.